# Proof of theorem involving a positive RV X

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I'm trying to understand the proof of the following theorem:

If $X \geq 0$ is a random variable, then
$$
\int_0^\infty x\ dF_x(x) = \int_0^\infty [1 - F_X(y)]\ dy.
$$
The proof is as follows:
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
\int_0^\infty x\ dF_x(x) &=& \int_0^\infty \bigg[ \int_0^x dy \bigg]\ dF_X(x)\\
 &=& \int_0^\infty \bigg[ \int_y^\infty dF_X(x) \bigg]\ dy\\
&=& \int_0^\infty [1 - F_X(y)]\ dy.
\end{eqnarray}
$$
Could someone please explain the change of integral in the second equality?

Comment: Do you know Fubini's theorem?

Comment: The proof cites Fubini's theorem, but I didn't understand what it meant.

Comment: Then you better [read up](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem) on it.

Comment: Helpful. I meant that I read Fubini's theorem and I didn't understand it, nor did I understand how it links to this. Could you explain it?

Comment: What exactly is it that you don't understand about Fubini's theorem or its application in this particular case?

Comment: Ok so the wikipedia version is extremely different to the one in my book. I now understand Fubini's Theorem, but I don't understand how come the bounds change. That is, why at the second equality isn't the bound on the outside integral $(0,x)$ and the bound on the inside integral $(0,\infty)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're integrating over the region $\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}^2:y<x\}$, which is an "infinite wedge" in the first quadrant. You can define this wedge in two ways: by saying that $x$ is unrestricted and $y$ varies between zero and $x$, or by saying that $y$ is unrestricted and $x$ is greater than $y$. The first way corresponds to the integral $\int_0^\infty{\left[\int_0^x\ldots\mathbb{d}y\right]\mathbb{d}x}$, the second to the integral $\int_0^\infty{\left[\int_y^\infty\ldots\mathbb{d}x\right]\mathbb{d}y}$.

The outer integral corresponds to the variable you specify first, and its limits are therefore always independent of the dummy variably of the inner integral.